# Making a JS function to delete a certain element

Tags: javascript, css, html, local-storage

I need to make a task board website for a school project and need to have a function to delete only one of the notes that was clicked on. A little overview of the code below - user inputs a value, a function puts the values in an object that is pushed into an array and then saved in local storage (using it is required for the project, just mentioning). After the value is saved, the function runs a For loop on the array and prints the notes with the values on them. That works just fine for me. What's the direction I should take with making the delete function? Any help or general direction would be really appreciated, as I feel like I'm really struggling over something that should be rather simple.

```js
// local storage function

var taskArray = [];

$(document).ready(function loadNotes() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("user tasks") === null) {
    console.log("local storage is empty");
    var alertDiv = document.getElementById("addAlert")
    alertDiv.innerHTML +=
      `
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable show hide">
          <strong>Welcome to our task board!</strong> Enter your task, and the app will keep track of it for you, even if you leave the page!
        </div>
    `
  } else {
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("maindiv");
    var arrayFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('user tasks');
    arrayFromStorage = JSON.parse(arrayFromStorage);
    $("#maindiv").empty();
    for (var index = 0; index < arrayFromStorage.length; index++) {
      mainDiv.innerHTML +=
        `
        <span class="relative">
        <img src="../assets/images/notebg.png" class="fade-in start imgSpacing" alt="">
        <span class="centerOnNote" id="textspan" onclick="deleteNote(this)">
        <span class="fas fa-times-circle"></span>
        <br>
        Your task = ${arrayFromStorage[index].name}
        Complete by = ${arrayFromStorage[index].date}
      </span>
   `
    }
  }
})

function saveToLocalStorage() {
  debugger;

  var taskName = document.getElementById("task").value;
  var taskDate = document.getElementById("date").value;

  var task = {
    name: taskName,
    date: taskDate
  }


  taskArray.push(task);
  var arrayToString = JSON.stringify(taskArray);
  localStorage.setItem("user tasks", arrayToString);
  var mainDiv = document.getElementById("maindiv");
  var arrayFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('user tasks');
  arrayFromStorage = JSON.parse(arrayFromStorage);
  $("#maindiv").empty();
  for (var index = 0; index < arrayFromStorage.length; index++) {
    mainDiv.innerHTML +=
      `
        <span class="relative">
          <img src="../assets/images/notebg.png" class="fade-in start imgSpacing" alt="">
          <span class="centerOnNote" id="textspan" onclick="deleteNote(this)">
          <span class="fas fa-times-circle"></span>
          <br>
          Your task = ${arrayFromStorage[index].name}
          Complete by = ${arrayFromStorage[index].date}
        </span>
      `

  }
}

function deleteNote(note) {
  
}
```

```css
.background-image {
  background-image: url("../assets/images/wallpaper/chalkboard.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
}

.pageheader {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.centerInput {
  margin: 10px 25px 30px 25px;
}

.imgContainer {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.fade-in.start {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.imgSpacing {
  padding: 2% 2% 2% 35px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
} 

.centerOnNote {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 45%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#textspan {
  width: 150px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body class="background-image">
  <h1 class="pageheader">My Task Board</h1>
  <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm centerInput" id="task" placeholder="Enter a Task">
        <input type="date" class="form-control col-sm centerInput" id="date" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="button" class="form-control btn btn-success" id="submit" value="Submit Task" onclick="saveToLocalStorage()">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="reset" class="form-control btn btn-success " id="reset" value="Reset Form">
      </div>
      <div id="addAlert">

      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!-- style="width: 70%; margin: auto; position: relative;" -->
  <div class="imgContainer" id="maindiv">
      
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `array.splice()` to remove the deleted "note" from your array, clear the container element and re-render the notes like you do when adding a note.

Comment: Just checking for clarification - there's no need to delete the actual pictures of the note? Just delete [index] from the array, clear the page, and print them again? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `this` to `deleteNote` which doesn't really help you, pass the current `index`:

```
  onclick="deleteNote(${index})"
```

that way you can `.splice()` out that index from the array and rerender / save to localStorage.

*PS: That string building is not the most elegant version though, instead you could use the DOM API and `.addEventListener`.*

Comment: 1. Could you elaborate on the first part of the answer a bit more? What I tried doing before is passing "this", saving it into a variable, and then using this.parentElement. When I checked to see if it works in the console it did, but when I deleted the note (which I thought it would only delete the one I pressed on) all of them got deleted, which is why I'm here.
2. I know there are definitely better ways to do what I do here, like more elegant ways, but I'm sort of restricted by what we learn in class and what I learn individually at home. I'll definitely try addEventListener. Thanks!

Comment: @dareRelaqz will `this.parentElement` is the `<span>` which won't get you any further

Comment: I tried doing this, when I'm pulling ${index} from the function right after I added a note, it works. When I do this after a page refresh (when it loads from local storage), it will still pick the span and then mess it up. I tried splitting it somehow, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: @dareRelaqz "it will still pick the span" ?? Don't mutate the DOM! Update the underlying datasteucture, than regenerate the view. It is hard to tell what exactly went wrong without seeing the code.